# EFI parition gone. How to boot recovery

Tags: windows-10, partitioning, multi-boot, uefi

I have a drive that for all intents and purposes the EFI partition can be considered gone. It will not boot. I have a recovery parition that has the folders

- Boot
- bootmgr
- BOOTNXT
- EFI
- sources

Inside sources is a file called boot.wim.

I want to be able to boot to this partition, load boot.wim and reset the computer with a fresh install.

I installed Linux. Afterwards Windows would not boot with and error like "bad system config". It was during toubleshooting that I followed some advice to format the EFI partition. I've tried to reload EFI from the recovery parition and the Windows partition. Neither worked. I just want to load the recovery and start over.

I have a USB that can get me to the recovery console. Is there something in the recovery console I can run to make the recovery drive the boot drive?

When I mount the recovery drive as F inside the recovery console and try to run `bcdboot F:\EFI /s V:\ /f UEFI` it says "failure when attempting to copy boot files". I can try with any of the directories listed above and it doesn't find the boot files it wants. I can run it with D:\Windows and it runs successfully but it doesn't get me anywhere.

Comment: No need to use a recovery partition that is potentially months, or years out of date and is potentially loaded with manufacturer junk. Download and create a fresh Windows 10 bootable installation USB drive with the Windows Media Creation Tool.

Comment: It’s a new computer. It has a hardware switch that loads a custom UEFI menu. I don’t want to loose all that. I just want to boot that image boot.wim.

Answer (score 0):

Installing Linux seems to have destroyed your boot environment.
Since according to what you say you do have a boot media which works,
you could use it to restore the boot environment as follows:

- [Boot to **Advanced Startup Options**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/2294-boot-advanced-startup-options-windows-10-a.html)
- [Run **Startup Repair**](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/27649-run-startup-repair-windows-10-a.html)

If this didn't fix the problem, next to try is
[Repair Install](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html).

Comment: Tried every one of the options on recovery media. None of them help the situation.

Comment: Added the next step.